# How do I fully expose a nested control in a UserControl to the outside?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, dependency-properties

Let's say I have a very simple `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.UserControls.MyControl">
    <DockPanel>
        <Label Content="lorem" />
        <Button Name="ButtonFromUserControl" />
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

For example, I want to access all properties of the `Button` from the outside if I add the `UserControl` in another file. I'm imagining something like this:

```
 <StackPanel>
     <usercontrols:MyControl Button.Dock="{Binding ButtonDockPosition}"/>
 </StackPanel>
```

I know that I can create dependency properties for each property to make them accessible, however I don't know yet which may or may not be used later and don't want to add a DP for each of the nested controls' properties.

I'm not sure if this would be the correct way to do it, if there is another way or pattern I'd be interested as well.

**Edit:**

I also tried to make the `Button` itself a DP, but that doesnt't let me access its properties:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty NestedButtonProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("NestedButton", typeof (Button), typeof (MyControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());
     
     
 public Button NestedButton => ButtonFromUserControl;
```

Comment: Do you want to access to controls just from XAML or in code-behind?

Comment: XAML would be ideal.

Comment: did you try to give the Button and the UserControl a name and then try to access it via XAML?

Comment: @Lennart I think WPF is not designed that way. If you want change a property of a control you should use binding. else make properties in your UserControl and on their change change the decedent control's value. but I think you already know that. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a kind of workaround which at least doesn't require me to generate huge amounts of forwarding DPs. Since most (or all?) of the controls' properties can be also set via a `Style`, I simply made the `Style` of each control a DP:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonStyleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ButtonStyle", typeof (Style), typeof (MyUserControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());

 public Style ButtonStyle
 {
     get { return (Style) GetValue(ButtonStyleProperty); }
     set { SetValue(ButtonStyleProperty, value); }
 }
```

Bind it in the `UserControl`:

```
 <Button Name="InnerButton" Style="{Binding ButtonStyle, ElementName=MyUserControl}" />
```

Now you can set the properties of the `Button` with a custom style:

```
 <userControls:MyUserControl>
    <userControls:MyUserControl.ButtonStyle>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="ButtonContent" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Orange" />
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </userControls:MyUserControl.ButtonStyle>
  </userControls:MyUserControl>
```

Comment: If you need to style nested elements, then your solution is typical for WPF.
Example: ItemsTemplate, ItemsContainerStyle - there are many more examples.
The only thing that raises doubts is the very use of the UserControl.
Its main purpose is to visualize the data received in the DataContext.
If you are not using DataContext bindings, then you should use Custom Control.